# how to override the recreation of fragments on screen flip

Tags: android

I have an activity that starts a fragment IF A CERTAIN BUTTON IS PRESSED (not in `onCreate()`). 
currently, after the fragment is started, if the screen is rotated, the fragment is automatically recreated.

Side question: Does this behavior sound normal? In the other posts I've seen relating to this, people seem to have to put in code to recreate the fragment.

I want override this functionality and manually re-create the fragment my self. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Can you show your code of your fragment, how you made the fragment transaction, and your manifest block of your activity too.

Comment: Is the fragment recreation a requirement? If not, override `onActivityCreated()` in your fragment and call `setRetainInstance(true)`, this will disable the recreation of the fragment during rotations. 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setRetainInstance(boolean) **Note**: This can only be used for fragments not on the backstack. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

This is normal, although its a pain in the neck.  You can override it by putting a configChange in your mainfest.  In that case, onConfigChanged in your Activity will be called when your device is rotated.  However if you're changing between different layouts for landscape and portrait you will then have to do that by hand.

Comment: Does this also override the functionality that restarts the Activity?

Comment: Yes, it does.  The restart of the Activity is actually what causes the recreation of the Fragment.